Moving from Spock 1.3 (groovy 2.4) to 2.x (groovy 4.0) Spy no longer work for constructors requiring args
In Spockframework 1.3 the following works for spy and then the spied object creates a closure MyClass is the closure's delegate.  In Spock 2.0, the closure doesn't set MyClass as its delegate.
instance = (MyClass) Spy(
         MyClass, 
         constructorArgs: [env, steps])

Classes Under Test
Class stores env and steps as this.env, this.steps.  It does not define getEnv() or getSteps()
This class is actually for a JenkinsShared library so the step is actual the vars groovy file's 'this' object which provides access to pipeline methods from within the library's source classes.
class JenkinsStepAccess{
 {
  public def env
  public def steps
  BaseClass(def env, def steps) {
    this.env = env
    this.steps = steps
  }
}

class DynamoDbManager extends JenkinsStepAccess {
  DynamoDbManager(def env, def steps) {
   super(env, steps)
  }

  def doThing() {
    // failing code as within the closure
    // this class is not the delegate automatically
    // in the newer Spock version, but is in the older
    def c = { this.steps.readFile(filePath)}
    def result = c()
  }
}

Test Classes
This project links JenkinsSci Pipeline Unit and SpockFramework together and must alter a delegate to do so.  However, given the contexts are orthogonal, I doubt that's the issue.
class PipelineTestHelper extends BasePipelineTest {
    // in this class we use PipelineUnit to replace Jenkins pipeline methods with our own
    // For instance readFile() gets replaced with our definition etc.  The content of this
    // class should not be important as the problem seems to relate to the classes under test
    // and this class isn't the spock class
}

class PipelineSpockTestBase extends Specification implements RegressionTest{

    /**
     * Delegate jenkins DSL to the helper class
     */
    @Delegate PipelineTestHelper pipelineTestHelper
    ...

    // again the majorty of this class methods aren't involved the the failure
    // they mainly are conveniance methods
}


class DynamoDbManagerTest extends PipelineSpockTestBase {
    // class under test
    DynamoDbManager dynamoDbManager

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        dynamoDbManager = (DynamoDbManager) Spy(DynamoDbManager, constructorArgs: [env, steps])
    }

    def thingTest() {
        given:
        ... not important ...

        when:
        dynamoDbManager.doThing('script text')
        ...
    }

In 2.0 this fails when anything references the steps fails with errors like:
No signature of method: MyClass.getSteps() 
is applicable for argument types: () values: []

The error only seems to happen when, within a closure, the Spy object attempts access of a field updated by the constructor.
// OK
steps.method()

// Failure
c = { steps.method() }
c()

Talking with copilot it seems that the issue is with the closure delegate and I can fix this a few ways

implement getters for fields ( add def getSteps() { return steps })
set delegate to this

c = { steps.method() }
c.delegate = this
c.() // ok

I haven't yet looked at before after to check what class is delegate in Spy case for spock 1.3 v 2.0.  I'll update this question after I do so

Do you have a simple reproducer?

@tim_yates updated the question.  There's something about the delegate for the closure that shifted.  On monday, I'll figure out what and update the question & answer it... maybe

What's MyClass where are env and steps coming from? I'm not saying you're wrong, it's just hard to repeat what you're seeing locally without a simple reproducer

Ah, got it.  Thanks and added the very simple example of MyClass and its base @tim_yates

Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. A member with 12.7k reputation should know better than just posting an incoherent set of snippets. Thank you.

@kriegaex thanks for the feedback, provided more context.  I'll do some checks around the closure  delegate in the two cases

Problem sorted.  It wasn't spock, it was groovy version shift, which I didn't include.  sorry about this.  this question started off as a mess and I should have written it up in a text doc and let it sit over the weekend vs going from hours of debugging various issues to vomiting text into here.

from copilot and modified by me:
This problem isn't the spock change but the groovy version change.
In groovy 2.x public properties can be access directly from a closure without the need to update delegate or create a getter method.  In 3.x/4.x the behavior changed requiring getters/setters.
This was caused by the introduction of @groovy.trandform.Field annotation in to control automated generation of getters/setters.  When the annotation is present, no getters or setters are created.
However, that specific feature is related but not the cause.  When executing within a closure, the scope changes leading to this order for lookup

local vairables
closure's delegate (default closure's delegate is to the closure itself according to copilot)
inclosing class
Groovy Closure class.

So, properties are going to stop at number 2 and hence given groovy's syntactic sugar between class fields/properties and automatate generation of getters/setters means that the attempt to access the field, expects a getter to exist.
The issue was never Spock and was always Groovy itself
So, even though in my debugger DynamoDbManager is listed as the closure delegate in both case but this case, according to copilot this is not the case

I do not know what your problem is due to your incomplete code and why you want to update to the outdated Spock 2.0 instead of the latest 2.4-M4. You also did not mention which Groovy version you use. I tried with 2.4-M4-groovy-4.0, and what you describe as being a problem seems to work fine:
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78318941

class Steps {
  def method() {}
}

package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78318941

class BaseClass {
  def env
  Steps steps

  BaseClass(def env, Steps steps) {
    this.env = env
    this.steps = steps
  }

  void foo() {
    bar('foo')
  }

  void bar(String s) {
    def c = { steps.method() }
    c()
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78318941

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  MyClass(def env, Steps steps) {
    super(env, steps)
  }
}

package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78318941

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyClassTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def env = 'my env'
    Steps steps = Mock()
    def instance = (MyClass) Spy(MyClass, constructorArgs: [env, steps])

    when:
    instance.foo()

    then:
    1 * instance.bar('foo')
    1 * steps.method()
  }
}

This works just fine, both in Spock 1.3 and 2.4-M4.
Try it in the Groovy Web Console.

Thanks, never was spock, always was shift from groovy 2.4 to 4.0 which I didn't include in the original text.  You were right to call me out.  I got very sloppy here

My Spock 1.3 test was with Groovy 2.5, I didn't go as far back as 2.4. Does my exact example fail there?

I'm not sure, given I have a solution and a details answer, I'm moving on.  It wasn't a spoke issue at all.  It is a groovy issue that shows up when groovy 3+ comes into play.  In addition, the project was designed to improve jacoco coverage accuracy, which it did not.  Finally, I realized that I need to continue to test using groovy version matching jenkins instance.  So, I abandoned this approach.  Never was spock
